# Adding appointments with a text description to a calendarview

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I've created a calendarview in my UWP app, and I can give the different days a background color via the CalendarViewDayItemChanging event. My goal is to create several appointments on a given day and display a text descpription for the appointment. How do I customize the CalendarViewDayItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event and get the `CalendarViewDayItem` instance from `CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs.Item`.

To set custom content as you require, you can set the `Template` property of the `CalendarViewDayItem` to a custom template and use `DataContext` to bind data.

Comment: Thanks- I've hardcoded an example style and template and it seems to be working. I've made a grid with a textblock for each event and different background colors for each row.

Comment: Great! If it solves the question, consider marking it as answer so that it is resolved :-).

Comment: I have a similar need, but I would like to add some colored squares inside any CalendarViewDayItem. An example to this answer would be useful.